# What datatype should I use when storing fingerprints?

Tags: fingerprint

I am using Digital Persona with OneTouch SDK in java in building my app.

I wonder what datatype should I store the the templates I scanned?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a template protection scheme.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you need to do with template :-)

A "standard" way to store template (list of minutiae) is to use [ISO 19794-2](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=38746) format.

There's 3 ISO formats for fingerprint template:

- Format Minutiae Record (FMR)
- Format Minutiae Card-Normal Size (FMC-NS)
- Format Minutiae Card-Compact Size (FMC-CS)

Comment: @JCFrane Is it useful ?